# How can I build an admin panel using firebase-admin

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, firebase, firebase-admin

I am trying to build a node/express/firebase-admin web app using vuejs in the front end but I am kind of confuse lets say I have two routes with express:

1. "/" the home page where users can sign up and log in and
2. "/admin" the admin page where administrators can do almost anything that the firebase-admin module can do

The problems is, and this is where I am confuse, the firebase-admin module only allows operations inside the server since there is where it lives the service account file with all the credentials. But how can I pass this privileges to my admin page without using the client SDK?

You cannot put the credentials inside your browser that is why I don't understand what is the communication that takes place between my admin page and the server. Someone on YouTube suggested me to build an api to send secure operations through it but since this endpoints lives inside the browser linked to button events anyone can see it and make requests to my server.

Maybe I am taking the wrong approach, I also thinking in use socket.io to send this secure operations but I think is lees secure than the first. If somebody could point me in the right I will be happy.

Comment: You can implement all non-privileged and user-level operations in the client-side using the Firebase JS SDK. For privileged operations, get the ID token of the currently signed in user, and send it to a secure server, where it can be validated using the Admin SDK. If the validation succeeds you can perform the privileged operation in the server. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details.

Comment: Yes I understand but how can I perform operations as an admin from the admin panel in the browser once I valited the user from the server? I mean how do I tell the admin: Hey! men you are an admin, here are this firebase-admin priviliged functions that you can perform from the browser...!

Comment: When you validate the user on the server, include a set of allowed operations in the response sent back to the client. Use this response to determine what operations to display on the UI.

Comment: After you validate the admin user on your backend (by checking the ID token), typically via an http endpoint, return some status to the client telling the client that user is an admin. The client can act like this is an admin user. However, you can't trust the client, so you need to enforce this in your database rules or on your server. Every time an authenticated request is sent to your server for an admin only resource, you check that the user is an admin, otherwise fail with an error notifying the client that the user is not an admin.

Comment: So then I don't need an admin page because if in my app I'm using the firebase client sdk (loginWithEmailandPassword method) anyone can login anyways whether they visit myapp.com or myapp.com/admin I mean its pointless even if I have the admin page in a subdomain its the same.

Comment: @Ahsath hey , how u solve this issue?

Comment: @OliverD well I didn't but if I were to do it I'll use https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions

Comment: @Ahsath i know cloud function that's to run a backend code  how can use it when i create admin panel? Any explanation

Comment: IDK I'm thinking adding an admin email in the firebase console, creating a login and block new users signup so you are the only one allow to login, create cloud functions for admin tasks, with each request firebase would add your user uid and validate it for you